# Reduce time taken in Line Sweep for vertical and horizontal line segments

Tags: algorithm, performance, c++11

I have used std::set to implement line sweep algorithm for vertical and horizontal lines. But the final range search on the lower bound and uppper bound of 'status' set takes a lot of time. Is there some way to avoid this? I chose std::set because it is based on balanced BST and insertion, deletion and search take logn time. Is there a better data structure to implement this?

```
// before this I initialize the events set with segments with increasing x co-ordinates. The segment struct has 2 points variable and 1 type variable for identifying vertical segment(1), horizontal segment starting(0) and ending(2).

for(auto iter = events.begin(); iter != events.end(); iter++)
    {
        segment temp = *iter;

        if(temp.type == 0)
            status.insert(temp.p1);
        else if(temp.type == 2)
            status.erase(temp.p2);
        else
        {    
            auto lower = status.lower_bound(std::make_pair(temp.p1.x, temp.p1.y));
            auto upper = status.upper_bound(std::make_pair(temp.p2.x, temp.p2.y));
            
            // Can the no of elements in the interval be found without this for loop
            for(;lower != upper; lower++)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here event and status are sets of segments struct and points respectively.

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> point;

struct segment
{
    point p1, p2;
    int type;

    segment(point a, point b, int t)
    :p1(a), p2(b), type(t){}
};

std::set<segment, segCompare> events;
...

std::set<point, pointCompare> status;
```

Comment: as status.lower_bound and status.upper_bound returns bidirectional iterators, I cannot substract them to find the size

Comment: What about using `std::distance(lower, upper)`? What is the size of `status` and `events`? What is the type of `status`' items ans `events`' items?

Comment: On casual inspection, it looks like `std::distance` would do the same thing as above.

Comment: Yes, std::distance does the same thing and doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compute the distance efficiently, the tree would need to maintain size counts for each sub-tree.  Since that service is not needed in most cases, it is not too surprising that `std::set` does not incur its cost for everyone.

I haven't found anything in the C++ standard library that will do this off the shelf.  I think you may need to roll your own in this case, or find someone else who has.

Answer (score 0):

If you do batch insertions of the events use a std::vector that is always sorted. There is no difference in asymptomatic runtime, which is O(n log n) for both, for a batch of n insertions.

This lets you do iterator arithmetic among other things.

Comment: From my understanding to find the no of horizontal lines intersection with the vertical iterator arithmetic should be done on the status. The status requires insertions, deletions as well as searching, so I prefered a BST type. The event set can be made a sorted vector and on second thought I think it will save some time iterating through it.

Comment: But iterating through it or a std::set will both have O(n). Am I right?

Comment: I tried making events a vector, but it doesn't solve the issue

Comment: The vector must always be sorted. If it is guaranteed to be sorted, it's functionality is identical to that of a set, except that it supports additional operations  that sets don't, such as iterator arithmetic.

Comment: The only advantage a std set has over a sorted std vector is when operations are not done in batches. For most realistic cases, this is not a significant advantage